# Texture Painting - stencil disappeared

Tags: texture-painting

I've been working the texture painting lesson in the apple tutorial by CGBoost.  Everything was working fine.  The stencil painting was working great and then the stencil disappeared.  I don't know what I did to make the stencil image disappear or how to get it back.  In watching the tutorial, there is a display dropdown in the draw tool.  I do not have that.  I am using 2.83.  When in the tutorial the alpha was reduced to 0 the stencil image disappeared and reappeared as the alpha was increased.  Since I don't have that drop down I can't do that.  It feels like my disappearance has to do with the alpha of the image - but how do I get to it.  Thanks.